# How to combine ssh and server variables

Tags: bash, shell

Please note that I'm trying to create a ssh connection using variables and I getting the below:

```
SSH_USR=test
SSH_HOST=1.1.1.1

ssh $SSH_USR@SSH_HOST
```

I get the below output:

`@1.1.1.1 - instead of the user and host.`

Any ideas on how I can get the values parsed?

Thibo

Comment: You forgot the `$` for `SSH_HOST`.

Comment: apologies the whole command is 
ssh $SSH_USR@$SSH_HOST and it still gives the same output.

Comment: Then you have a typo that you aren't reproducing in the question.

Comment: The code you gave doesn't show the problem, which means there is some critical part of your script/environment/etc that you haven't included in the question (probably because you don't realize it's involved/relevant). The best way to solve this is to trim your script down to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The problem may become clear as you do that, but if not, edit your question to include the repro code so we can look at it. But be sure to post the *exact* code, so we're not pointing out different problems than the real one.

Comment: Also, two general recommendations: run your code through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) and fix what it points out, and switch to lower- or mixed-case variable names (there are a bunch of all-caps names with special meanings, and you can cause trouble by accidentally using one of those).

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the variables you initialized you must precede the variable name with a dollar sign $ whenever you reference the value it contains.

Since you used it correctly before SSH_USR I think you just made a typo and missed it for SSH_HOST:

```
SSH_USR=test
SSH_HOST=1.1.1.1

echo SSH_USR is $SSH_USR
echo SSH_HOST is $SSH_HOST
echo final statement is ssh $SSH_USR@$SSH_HOST

ssh $SSH_USR@$SSH_HOST
```

Comment: I've tried it with the above and it still produces the same output where it returns just the ip address

Comment: Tested it, works perfectly on my Ubuntu.
I add a few echo so that you can debug.
Please remove your script and paste mine as is.

Comment: Hi there,

if you found my code useful please don't forget upvoting it and/or choosing it as final answer.